# PostgreSQL : Prevent SQL Injection in pl/pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

I am trying to handle sql injection related to startdate and enddate in the below pl/pgsql function.

Let's say If I provide startdate as '2019-10-02' and end date as the following :

2019-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND rid in ('R1857745') group by rid, dcid UNION ALL SELECT 'R1857745'::character(8) , 'D099901'::character(8), 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM pg_shadow --

The above value for enddate creates a serious SQL vulnerability.

```
create function A(
 in startdate varchar(10),
 in enddate varchar(10))
RETURNS setof AB AS $$
BEGIN
 return query execute
 'select rid,dcid,
        sum(case when id between 10 and 19 or id between 21 and 26 then noOfcaptured else 0 end) total_tilldate,
        sum(case when dateofevent>=to_date(''' || startdate || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and (id between 10 and 19 or id between 21 and 26) then noofcaptured else 0 end) total_range,
        sum(case when id not between 51 and 59 then cast(sizecaptured as double precision)/1048576 else 0 end) totalsize_tilldate,
        sum(case when dateofevent>=to_date(''' || startdate || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and id not between 51 and 59 then cast(sizecaptured as double precision)/1048576 else 0 end) totalsize_range
   from repostats
  where dateofevent<=to_date(''' || enddate || ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') ' 
  group by rid, dcid';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As startdate and enddate are of variable type date, so we can do validation with date formats. But, I really don't want to do that because in this scenario I am more concerned about **single quote**.

I know that we can escape **'** by using 2 single quotes i.e. **''**

Is there any public function available in postgreSQL which can escape **single quote**, so that we can use the same for all type of variables in where clause or in other places.

*I tried using* **quote_literal**, *but it's not doing the job for me*

Comment: you don't need dynamic SQL for this to begin with

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter - probably you can help with the answer to this question, thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name waiting for your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: As I said: don't use dynamic SQL to begin with if it's not needed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's very legacy code and I need to go with dynamic SQL, can you suggest any other alternatives ?

Comment: Use `date` as the input type?  But if you can edit the function body, you could just as well remove the dynamic SQL...

Comment: @dezso Thanks for taking interest in this. As you mentioned, using date as the input type is also an option and it's the correct thing to do. But, I am just interested in knowing is there any other way to fix this problem. Tried to use using along with execute, still no luck.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have used execute along with using clause by taking $1, $2 as the values of startdate and enddate. Removed the concatenation inside to_date() and changed it to to_date($1, ''YYYY-MM--DD''). Thanks for your valuable suggestions and spending some time on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter placeholders instead of concatenating the input into the SQL string.

```sql
create function A(in startdate varchar(10), in enddate varchar(10))
  RETURNS setof AB AS $$
declare
  l_startdate date;
  l_enddate date;
BEGIN
 l_startdate := to_date(startdate,'YYYY-MM-DD');
 l_enddate := to_date(enddate,'YYYY-MM-DD'); 

 return query execute
 'select rid,dcid,
        sum(case when id between 10 and 19 or id between 21 and 26 then noOfcaptured else 0 end) total_tilldate,
        sum(case when dateofevent >= $1 and (id between 10 and 19 or id between 21 and 26) then noofcaptured else 0 end) total_range,
        sum(case when id not between 51 and 59 then cast(sizecaptured as double precision)/1048576 else 0 end) totalsize_tilldate,
        sum(case when dateofevent >= $2 and id not between 51 and 59 then cast(sizecaptured as double precision)/1048576 else 0 end) totalsize_range
   from repostats
  where dateofevent<= $3
  group by rid, dcid'
    using l_startdate, l_startdate, l_enddate;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```